# How to send a single request to different dialogflow agents in a loop?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to send a single user query to multiple agents in different google projects in order to get the confidence score and then choose the better agent to proceed. When I send a request to a single agent, it works fine, but when I try to loop the console shows 'IAM access denied'.

I tried to update the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the environment variable and create different SessionClient for request to different agent in the loop. The given code is similar to what I am trying to do.

```
let agents = [{projectID:"xyz", keyfile: "xyz.json"}, {projectID:"abc", keyfile: "abc.json"}]    

let sessionClient;
let sessionPath;
let dfRequest = <some queryInput object set>;

for(let agent of agents){
  process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = agent.keyfile;
  sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
  sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(agent.projectID,'123sessionID');
  dfRequest.session = sessionPath;
  sessionClient.detectIntent(dfRequest);
}
```

I believe detectIntent returns promise and those things can be handled later. But here my first request gives me the correct response, but the next request gives authentication problem. Please help!

The exact error I am getting:

```
{ Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/xyz-123/agent' denied.
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (D:\myProject\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules\grpc\src\common.js:91:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\myProject\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1204:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (D:\myProject\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (D:\myProject\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (D:\myProject\node_modules\google-gax\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:845:24)
  code: 7,
  metadata:
   Metadata { _internal_repr: { 'grpc-server-stats-bin': [Array] } },
  details:
   'IAM permission \'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent\' on \'projects/xyz-123/agent\' denied.' }
```